# Search Multiple Tables of a Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have the following code:

```
    $query = "select * from customer where Surname  like \"%$trimmed%\" OR TitleName  like \"%$trimmed%\" OR PostCode  like \"%$trimmed%\"
  order by Surname";
```

However, I have another table which I want to search from with the same paramaters(variables) as that. I know that something like "`select * from customer,othertable`" might not be possible, Is there a way to do it?

By using UNION it cuts my page off, and doesnt even search it properly

```
    $query = "select * from customer where Surname  like \"%$trimmed%\" OR TitleName  like \"%$trimmed%\" OR PostCode  like \"%$trimmed%\"
  order by Surname UNION select * from mooring where Number like \"%$trimmed%\"";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`UNION`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator to search from multiple tables.

Comment: most webhosting companies disables this feature as it decreases the security and increases the options for sql injection if there was a hole in passing the variables used in queries

Comment: I altered my code to use the UNION thing, and half of my page dissapears and doesnt even search it properly. I will post my code on my Question

Comment: @Ronan Dejhero: I can't say that most do it but yes some do disable it for security reasons.

Comment: @DogPooOnYourShoe: You should post your altered code in your question again :)

Comment: @DogPooOnYourShoe: Number of columns and data type of both fields must match for union to work.

Comment: I can't match them as I only need one field from the 2nd DB and about 3 from the other.

Comment: try using `left join` if tables are related then.

Comment: They arent related. I would expect MYSQL to implement something which would allow me to search 2 different tables without them being related.

Comment: @DogPooOnYourShoe, Why don't you just search each table separately if they aren't related?

Comment: As I can only return one result, as this is a search which needs to search 2 DIFFERENT tables

Comment: add the right 3 fields in the first, and in the second add the first field (which must have the same type as the first field on the first query) and then 2 stubs, like "nothing","nothingagain" for the remaining 2 fields. And then set your order by AFTER the union query, at the end, and not in the queries.

Comment: You can disable the `UNION` operator? How come?

Answer (score 1):

If your table structures are different you will have to use multiple queries and multiple fragments of code to handle the different type of results. Alternately, you can select only the similar fields from the two tables using the UNION operator. You can null out the fields that do not match up. Consider this:

```
SELECT CustomerID, Surname, PostCode, NULL AS Number, 'CUSTOMER' AS Type 
# Suppose that the 'Number' column does not exist in this table
FROM   Customer
WHERE  Surname   LIKE '%$trimmed%'
OR     TitleName LIKE '%$trimmed%'
OR     PostCode  LIKE '%$trimmed%'

UNION

SELECT MooringID,  Surname, NULL,     Number,         'MOORING'
# Suppose that the 'PostCode' column does not exist in this table
FROM   Mooring
WHERE  Number    LIKE '%$trimmed%'

ORDER BY 2 # ORDER BY goes to the very end of the union query in this case
```

Answer (score 1):

Your UNION syntax is incorrect.

1. The number of columns and types must be the same. If this is not the case use two queries.
2. The ORDER BY must go at the end of your query, not before a UNION.